# Add a picker view at the bottom of the screen in a tableview controller

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have a tableview controller with many statics cells. When i click on one field, i want to display a UIPicker to pick a value.

My table is big, so it's scrollable.

How can i add a subview on my tableviewController to display this UIPicker at the bottom of the ipad screen, i mean not at the bottom of the tableview.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get CGRect from viewDidAppear (not viewDidDisplay). In there self.bounds (if you have a UITableViewController class is hard when we don't see your code) return you a visible area only. Then you can draw a picker there.

Edit (for comment request):
I use example for that from my code. In your viewController (any tableView, View ... ) you have two methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%f,%f",self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);
}
```

What i do above is paste the same code to both methods. What i did receive:
From viewDidLoad: 320.000000,460.000000
From viewDidAppear: 320.000000,416.000000

This is becouse i have navigationBar in the top. So if you have something on the screen you should draw it in CGRect whatever you like (percent value maybe).

Comment: Thank you but can you explain me more? I am starting objective C and it's hard for me to understand your answer.

Comment: Thank you. But the fact is that i want to position my view relative to the ipad screen and not to the table view. Because if i put the view relative to the table view, it will move when i scroll on my table. Do you understand my problem? :)